# CTRL+T Shortcut

Tags: shortcut

While i was watching some tutorials and at some sites, i saw people could add image texture, mapping and texture coordinater nodes at ones in node editor with CTRL+L shorcut. It is a really useful shortcut when you add lots of those nodes. But for some reason, nothing happens when i choose one node and hit CTRL+T. Is there any option you need to active that ? or not functional anymore?

Comment: To make this shortcut work you need to enable the **Node Wrangler** add on.

Comment: On this site(http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/), i just read "Note: Node Wrangler is included in Blender by default, so you probably already have it installed." So, i thought i had it already.

Comment: Oh, i have found it at Preferences > Add-ons > Nodes. Thank you :)

Comment: Please close topic if solved

Comment: @MCunha, Wouldn't you rather it stay in case someone has some matter and may read here as solution ?

Comment: It won't disappear... Marking it as closed, only refers that you really do have found an answer!

Comment: How do you close it ?

Answer (score 4):

I think that's node wrangler http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/ A MUST HAVE ADDON

Comment: Yes, then i learnt i needed to active it at  Preferences > Add-ons > Nodes: Node Wrangler. It really like it!