# Quickly add texture coordinate and mapping nodes shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

I know there will be a very quick and easy answer to this if someone knows it. I've seen it a few times in some videos where these two nodes can be added in with just a shortcut but i can't seem to remember how to do it or find the videos which show it. I do have the node wrangler add on. Using blender 2.79b.

thank you

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93894/ctrlt-shortcut

Answer (score 7):

[image: Search menu]Just figured this one out. Ctrl+T will do just that. The action is named "Texture Setup" in case you wanted to use the search function to edit the hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

$\small \color {brown} {\text {For Blender version 3.1 with Node Wrangler}}$

The short answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> which is the shortcut for the command `Add Texture Setup`. But this works only if you installed the [Node Wrangler](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) plugin, it's not part of Blender itself.

Node wrangler shortcuts can be found in the documentation and in the plugin setup. In addition certain operations are directly accessible using the right panel in the shader editor area, including the one you're looking for. This menu can also be accessed using the Node Wrangler contextual menu which shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.

Last but not least, provided you know the name, as any other command it can be found in the search box displayed by <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, entering a portion of `add texture setup`:

> [image]

(Now you can access all the plugin commands and their shortcuts, you may be interested in using some other, like `Swap Links` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>) which can swap to inputs, e.g. on a Math node.

Details follow if you're interested.

**Plugin setup in User Preferences**

Go to user preferences, search the plugin and open `Hotkey List section`:

[image]

In this section, among tens of shortcuts, you'll find:

> [image]

**Using the documentation**

From the same user preferences page, click on the related link, which reaches [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) (varies with Blender version):

> [image]

Note this command `Add Texture Setup` is smart enough to work both on the texture node and on the shader node.

**In the right panel of the shader editor**

When installing Node Wrangler plugin, a tab is added to the right panel (sidebar) of the editor. This panel can be shown / hidden by the shortcut <kbd>N</kbd> or using the area menu `View|Sidebar`:

[image]

**Using the Node Wrangler menu shortcut**

The same menu can be displayed using the menu shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> in the shader editor.

---

**The other Add Texture command**

Node Wrangler also offers `Add Principled Setup` which shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>. It can be used with a principled shader node to add different textures at the same time, along with the coordinate mapping:

[image]

This command is not documented (at the time of the writing, the plugin online documentation is not up to date for 3.1 anyway). However from [the code](https://fossies.org/linux/blender/release/scripts/addons/node_wrangler.py) it is possible to see textures are associated to Principled BSDF shader using pre-defined substrings in the texture name:

```
name='Base Color',
default='diffuse diff albedo base col color',
description='Naming Components for Base Color maps'

name='Subsurface Color',
default='sss subsurface',
description='Naming Components for Subsurface Color maps'

name='Metallic',
default='metallic metalness metal mtl',
description='Naming Components for metallness maps'

name='Specular',
default='specularity specular spec spc',
description='Naming Components for Specular maps'

name='Normal',
default='normal nor nrm nrml norm',
description='Naming Components for Normal maps'

name='Bump',
default='bump bmp',
description='Naming Components for bump maps'

name='Roughness',
default='roughness rough rgh',
description='Naming Components for roughness maps'

name='Gloss',
default='gloss glossy glossiness',
description='Naming Components for glossy maps'

name='Displacement',
default='displacement displace disp dsp height heightmap',
description='Naming Components for displacement maps'
```