# Using texture from substance painter (tri plannar projection)?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]i create texture using substance painter, then use it on blender principle BSDF, but the result so ugly different from the result on substance painter, i expect its because of the triplanar projection
any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image texture is not mapped correctly on the surface, did you check, if your Texture matches your UVs? And add a Texture Coordinate and a Mapping node to your Material-Setup. The easiest way to do that is to use the Node-Wrangler-Addon ([CTRL+T Shortcut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/93894/92817)), it should be activated by default in blender 2.8, select the Principled BSDF Node and import your maps by using the shortcut CTRL+T, the add-on should create the right Node-Setup. Then check if the texture-mapping is made by the UV-map. All the best Marco Vitale

Comment: yeah i put the wrong box instead of flat on the image texture node,
but still the texture is not seamless, i still can see some line in the object
in substance painter everything is good, what am i missing?

Comment: Can you post another screenshot, maybe one with the UV-Editor open as well? And maybe one from substance painter?